# npm doesn't have unlink command in the docs

Tags: npm

If I go to npm commands https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands there is no such command as `unlink`, however, it seems that this is the only way you can remove symbolic links (if you have some). So, the way I could remove symbolic links I found not in official npm docs but on other resources. Does anybody know why this command is missing in npm docs?
I thought maybe in version 8 it was somehow removed/changed, but even in older versions the same thing - no unlink command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `unlink` command is an *alias* of the `uninstall` command.

The commands; `unlink`, `remove`, `rm`, `r`, and `un`, are all essentially an *alias* of the `uninstall` command. Therefore you can utilise any one of the aforementioned keywords/commands for the same purpose.

Refer to the [`uninstall`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-uninstall) command in the npm docs for further information. As you can see the *”Synopsis”* section states the following:

> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> npm uninstall [<@scope>/]<pkg>...
>
> aliases: unlink, remove, rm, r, un
> ```